# Creating web services using node.js

Tags: javascript, database, web-services

So, I have 3 javascript files that do the following:

- database.js: connects to the database and runs sql commands (insert, delete, update, select).
- mid.js: runs a method and sends the results to the database.js file to insert them into the database.
- main_file.js: calls the mid.js method and calls the database.js file to run sql commands.

My question is: since main_file.js and mid.js cannot access directly to the database, I am suppose to develop some HTTP web services that will stay between my client-side javascript files (mid.js and main_file.js) and my database file (database.js). How can I create all the services and keep the above flow?

Important: some of the sql commands return a value that is used in other sql command. For example, an insert command returns an id that is going to be used in a select command.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like something for Docker and Kubernetes

Comment: use rpc, there are libs for that https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rpc-2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Open database port to application server and directly connect to database. There are some security measures but avoiding another abstraction layer is an advantage.
2. At database side create the rest API which app server calls their endpoint (close to what is called `web service` in Windows terminology). THis abstraction level can do some extra work based on your scenario but still need to use API key for security.

After all the design decisions are based on the project.